# Why reducing the length of an array makes last element undefined but the length doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I'm new to javascript.

I was trying to reduce the length of an array by 1.

I did this, the last element is `undefined` now, but the length is still 5.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.length = arr.length--;

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
```

I'm confused. Instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Why it gives me `[1, 2, 3, 4, undefined]`?

Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: Try `array.length = array.length - 1`

Comment: Simply `array.length--;` would also work. The pre- and post-increment/decrement operators change the value of the variable or property; there's no need for an additional assignment.

Comment: You can also use pre decrement operator to perform this `arr.length = --arr.length;` but `arr.length--` will do everything, no need to assign it back

Comment: Using `--` and `++` as part of a larger expression is a recipe for disaster. For goodness' sake, don't write things like `x = x--`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr.length--` will reduce the length by `1` already but will *return the previous length*, meaning you're reducing the array's length by 1 and then immediately assigning the previous length to `arr.length`, meaning you're changing it back to a five element array (but you already removed the fifth element ,so that's now `undefined`.

If you want to just reduce the array's length, you can user `arr.length--;` alone.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.length--;

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `array.prototype.pop` you instead to reduce the size of your array:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 arr.pop();

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
```

Take into consideration that `arr.length--` with a length of 0 causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

A timeline of what's happening in `array.length = array.length--`:

- The `--` operator changes `array.length` from `5` to `4`.
- `array.length--` evaluates to the *previous* value of `array.length`, which is `5`
- This value is assigned to `array.length`, changing it from `4` to `5`.

So you are shrinking the array and then growing it.

My advice: avoid mutating your arrays and instead use `slice`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var newArr = arr.slice(0, -1);

console.log(newArr);
console.log(newArr.length);
```

If you insist on mutating your arrays, then I suggest you use a less mystifying operator: `-=`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.length -= 1;

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
arr.splice(arr.length-1);

console.log(arr);        //[1,2,3,4]   --Expected Log 
console.log(arr.length); //4           --Expected Log
```

Or you can try this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.pop();

console.log(arr);        //[1,2,3,4]   --Expected Log 
console.log(arr.length); //4           --Expected Log
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want reduce  , you can use 'splice'

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.